# Instead of having a new set of data, How can I just add the quantity of the item

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a 2 datagridview 
1 is DgCahier
2 is DgAddtoCart

my code when passing the data from dgcashier to dgAddtoCart is this:

```
 private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (add1.Text == "Change Quantity")
        {
            select = DGAddToCart.Rows[i];
            select.Cells[5].Value = quan.Text;
            select.Cells[7].Value = subTotal.Text;
            String str = "update tbl_book 
                          set book_quan=book_quan - " + quan.Text + " 
                          where book_code = " + code.Text + "";
            db.updateData1(str);
           String srt="update tbl_damagebook 
                       set dbook_quan=dbook_quan - " + quan.Text + "
                       where dam_id = " + code.Text + "";
            db.updateData1(srt);
            add1.Text = "Add to Cart";
            Total();
            clear1();
        }
        else
        {
            if (quan.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input Quantity", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else if (quan.Text.StartsWith("-"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Do not input neagtive quntity", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            } else if (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) < int.Parse(quan.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not enough Stocks!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                DGAddToCart.Rows.Add(code.Text, title.Text, author.Text, edition.Text,year.Text, quan.Text, price.Text, subTotal.Text);



                String strq = "update tbl_book 
                               set book_quan=book_quan - " + quan.Text + " 
                               where book_code=" + code.Text + "";
                db.updateData1(strq);

                String str1 = "update tbl_damagebook 
                               set dbook_quan=dbook_quan - " + quan.Text + " 
                               where dam_id=" + code.Text + "";
                db.updateData1(str1);
```

my problem is if I add the same item with same description it does not add the current item selected instead it adds a new item with the same description.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried your queries with simple values in your query editor ? Furthermore you should use a UNIQUE PK in your table.

Comment: You just need to check if data is already present in the `DgAddtoCart` by looping through the data in it and if the data is already present in the `DgAddtoCart` then update the value of quantity instead of adding every time. You may refer this code to update `dataGridView1.Rows[RowNumber].Cells[CC.Index].Value = quan.Text;`